# Using MySQL CURTIME() & ADDTIME() how do you combat midnight transitions?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (flightSched) which contains flight numbers, flights arrival days, whether they arrive or depart and most importantly their **Arrival times** as illustrated below.

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| FlightNo    | don            | depOrArriv      | arrivalTime     | 
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| ET821       | Daily          | Arrival         | 19:45:24        |
| MS838       | Tuesday        | Arrival         | 00:05:24        |
| H7361       | Tuesday        | Arrival         | 23:15:06        |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I would like to display all the flights in the table that are between the current time and four hours ahead of the current time.

Find below my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM flightSched
WHERE  `arrivalTime` 
BETWEEN CURTIME() 
AND ADDTIME( CURTIME() ,  '04:00:00' ) 
ORDER BY arrivalTime ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The query works perfectly until a flight arrives/departs beyond midnight. Based on the table above, If the current time was 21:00:00, flight number MS838 will not be displayed. 
Where am I going wrong?

Can anyone kindly point out where I am going wrong in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I finally figured it all out!

Because I need a query to be able to differentiate between flights arriving during the current day and the next day after midnight (based on time), I had to slightly re-structure the table (flightSched) by changing the arrivalTime column data from TIME to DATETIME. Subsequently, this now means that the content in this column is saved in this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or (2013-11-22 12:30:00) instead of just 12:30:00, which is much richer.

I then noticed that the query below arithmetically calculates the time correctly way into the next day/date after midnight.

If the current time is 21:00

```
//################################################
//## Subtract the 30 minutes from the current time
mysql> SELECT SUBTIME(NOW(), '00:30:00' );
+-------------------------------------+
| SUBTIME(NOW(),  '00:30:00' )        |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2013-11-22 20:30:00                 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

//################################################
//## Add the 4 hours to the current time


mysql> SELECT ADDTIME(NOW(),  '04:00:00');
+-------------------------------------+
| ADDTIME(NOW() ,  '04:00:00' )       |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2013-11-23 01:00:00                 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

NOTE! how perfectly the date changed as well from 2013-11-22 21:00:00 to the 2013-11-23 01:00:00.
 :-)

Using the table below

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| FlightNo    | don            | depOrArriv      | arrivalTime         | 
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| ET821       | Daily          | Arrival         | 2013-11-22 19:45:24 |
| MS838       | Tuesday        | Arrival         | 2013-11-23 01:05:24 |
| H7361       | Tuesday        | Arrival         | 2013-11-22 23:15:06 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Running query:

```
SELECT * FROM flightSched WHERE arrivalTime
                                 BETWEEN  SUBTIME(NOW(), '00:30:00')
                 AND ADDTIME(NOW(),'04:00:00')
                 ORDER BY arrivalTime ASC
```

Yields:

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| MS838       | Tuesday        | Arrival         | 2013-11-23 01:05:24 |
| H7361       | Tuesday        | Arrival         | 2013-11-22 23:15:06 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Thank you very much for you Time and Effort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because `ADDTIME` is not doing what you think, look at the following examples:

```
mysql> SELECT ADDTIME( '19:59:59' ,  '04:00:00' );
+-------------------------------------+
| ADDTIME( '19:59:59' ,  '04:00:00' ) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 23:59:59                            |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT ADDTIME( '20:00:01' ,  '04:00:00' );
+-------------------------------------+
| ADDTIME( '20:00:01' ,  '04:00:00' ) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 24:00:01                            |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

A possible solution is to change the query `WHERE` clause to use `TIMEDIFF`, and then ensure the difference is between specific ranges.

If we take some example values of time and compare the `TIMEDIFF` results with mid-day we get the following:

```
+----------+---------------------------------+
| time     | TIMEDIFF(MAKETIME(12,0,0),time) |
+----------+---------------------------------+
| 01:00:00 | 11:00:00                        |
| 03:00:00 | 09:00:00                        |
| 05:00:00 | 07:00:00                        |
| 07:00:00 | 05:00:00                        |
| 11:00:00 | 01:00:00                        |
| 13:00:00 | -01:00:00                       |
| 15:00:00 | -03:00:00                       |
| 17:00:00 | -05:00:00                       |
| 19:00:00 | -07:00:00                       |
| 21:00:00 | -09:00:00                       |
| 23:00:00 | -11:00:00                       |
+----------+---------------------------------+
```

Times in the future result in a negative time difference (with the arguments supplied in the order shown), so for times that haven't wrapped around we know that any range between -00:00:00 and -04:00:00 are acceptable (based on your update of 0 - 4hours ahead.

So to check normal no wrapped times the following should work:

TIMEDIFF( CURTIME() ,  `arrivalTime` ) 
      BETWEEN MAKETIME(-4,0,0) AND MAKETIME(0,0,0)

If we then examine values that do wrap:

```
+----------+----------------------------------+
| time     | TIMEDIFF(MAKETIME(23,30,0),time) |
+----------+----------------------------------+
| 01:00:00 | 22:30:00                         |
| 03:00:00 | 20:30:00                         |
| 05:00:00 | 18:30:00                         |
| 07:00:00 | 16:30:00                         |
| 11:00:00 | 12:30:00                         |
| 13:00:00 | 10:30:00                         |
| 15:00:00 | 08:30:00                         |
| 17:00:00 | 06:30:00                         |
| 19:00:00 | 04:30:00                         |
| 21:00:00 | 02:30:00                         |
| 23:00:00 | 00:30:00                         |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```

We see that values over 20 hours should be acceptable.

```
  OR TIMEDIFF( CURTIME() ,  `arrivalTime` ) > MAKETIME(20,0,0)
```

With the change in requirement to 30m to 4h time difference it maybe worth changing the approach completely to convert the entire timestamp to seconds past midnight and then comparing the difference, modulo that on the number of seconds in a day and check the result of that.

Comment: Sorry about the number of edits to this answer, I have tested this solution and I believe it works. Does anybody have a more elegant solution?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out were I was going wrong. I did try out your query and I doesn't yield any results. Also looking at your solution, I want all the results between 30 minutes ago and 4 hours from now to show, and not four hours ago to the current time. More suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, kindly explain how to interpret this TIMEDIFF( CURTIME() ,  `arrivalTime` )

Comment: It should result in the number of hours:minutes:seconds difference. Experiment with SELECT TIMEDIFF('01:00:00', '02:00:00'); etc. Then try comparing with >, < and BETWEEN and MAKETIME(h,m,s)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Please bear with me, I am kind of new to PHP and MySQL. If I understand it correctly then your code BETWEEN MAKETIME(-4,0,0) AND MAKETIME(0,0,0) means Between 4 hours ago and the current time. Am I right? If so I have come up with something abit closer to home: SELECT * 
FROM  `flightSched` 
WHERE  `arrivalTime` 
BETWEEN MAKETIME( -4, 0, 0 ) 
AND MAKETIME( 20, 0, 0 )

Comment: Kindly help me understand how to formulate BETWEEN MAKETIME( -4, 0, 0 ) AND MAKETIME( 20, 0, 0 ). To read between current time minus 30 minutes and four hours from the current time. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: The BETWEEN syntax allows you to specify a range of possible values. Here we are saying where the result of TIMEDIFF is between the ranges.